# How can I install php-fpm on a windows machine,with apache as the web server?

Tags: php, apache

Sorry if this is not a very programming-specific but I have researched on the internet for quite some time and I just could not find an answer to this question.

Please someone walk me thorugh the installation process.

Thanks

Comment: What have you googled so far?

Comment: I have googled "php-fpm install".And,the best resource I have come across is the php manual(as always :))).However I could not understand what file should I edit. http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php

Comment: Finding the right software package is off-topic. Just go and get whatever XAMPP has ready. You don't really need FPM on Windows, since this is not going to be anything more than a test/development setup. (The configuration would be the same on each platform though). Just use `mod_php` or whatever is preconfigured. Don't hunt for custom setup tutorials without a good reason. (Asking for a complete tutorial here is a bit too broad.)

Comment: You might have gotten the wrong idea about me :)).I have xampp installed.I am a php developer.I am currently building a pretty big app that demands a lot from my server.That is why I am trying to install fpm or any fast-cgi actually.I wanted to install it on my pc first,so that when I deploy the app,I already know how to set up my server properly.I am not very accustomed to custom php configurations and that is why I needed this information,but whatever..

Comment: The php.ini for FPM is the same as the standard configuration file. It just has an extra connection pool and named sockets. The Apache httpd.conf configuration for FPM/FastCGI is way more work.

Comment: Are you really planning to use a windows server for PHP and run php-fpm there? How about using Vagrant https://github.com/vesselinv/vagrant-lemp - https://github.com/marcojanssen/vagrant-ansible